# regarding re-factoring python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

so I have this python file which looks out for all the "label" tags in a XML file and does some modification with it. label is a string containing at max three lines. the code is manipulating XML file.

```
                    #1 label="Number of Packets Transmitted by the Source
                            Node of the Path to the Destination Node Of
                            the Path"
                    #2 label="Number of Packets Transmitted by the Source
                            node of the path to the destination node of
                            the path"
```

notice in label #2 words in second and third line are not in upper case which is not what I want. I want help in correcting logic of my program such that I should not write label twice.

```
import os
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

def splitAndMakeTitleCase(line):
    # does something not relevant to context



fileList = open("AllFiles")
for fileStr in fileList:
    fileName = fileStr.rstrip('\n')
    openFile = open(fileName)
    openNewFile = open(fileName+'TitleCase.xml','w')
    lines = openFile.readlines()
    for lineIndex in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[lineIndex]
        skip = 0
        if "label=" in line and "const" not in line:
            segs = line.split('"')
            if len(segs) >= 3:
                pass
            else:
                openNewFile.write(lines[lineIndex])
                secondTitleCaseLine = splitAndMakeTitleCase(lines[lineIndex + 1])
                skip = lineIndex + 1
                openNewFile.write(secondTitleCaseLine)
                if '"' not in lines[lineIndex + 1]:
                    thirdTitleCaseLine = splitAndMakeTitleCase(lines[lineIndex + 2])
                    skip = lineIndex + 1
                    openNewFile.write(thirdTitleCaseLine)
        openNewFile.write(lines[lineIndex])
    openFile.close()
    openNewFile.close()
    #cmd = "mv " + fileName + "TitleCase.xml " + fileName
    #os.system(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you have the first if and then within that you do some printing to the file. Then after that you do another print of the line to the file. I think that you probably want that last line in a else like this:

```
for fileStr in fileList:
    fileName = fileStr.rstrip('\n')
    openFile = open(fileName)
    openNewFile = open(fileName+'TitleCase.xml','w')
    lines = openFile.readlines()
    for lineIndex in range(0,len(lines)):
        line = lines[lineIndex]
        skip = 0
        if "label=" in line and "const" not in line:
            segs = line.split('"')
            if len(segs) >= 3:
                pass
            else:
                openNewFile.write(lines[lineIndex])
                secondTitleCaseLine = splitAndMakeTitleCase(lines[lineIndex + 1])
                skip = lineIndex + 1
                openNewFile.write(secondTitleCaseLine)
                if '"' not in lines[lineIndex + 1]:
                    thirdTitleCaseLine = splitAndMakeTitleCase(lines[lineIndex + 2])
                    skip = lineIndex + 1
                    openNewFile.write(thirdTitleCaseLine)
        else:
            openNewFile.write(lines[lineIndex])
    openFile.close()
    openNewFile.close()
    #cmd = "mv " + fileName + "TitleCase.xml " + fileName
    #os.system(cmd)
```